# Theano's function() reports that my `givens` value is not needed for the graph

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, conv-neural-network

Sorry for not posting entire snippets -- the code is very big and spread out, so hopefully this can illustrate my issue. I have these:

```
train = theano.function([X], output, updates=update_G,
                        givens={train_mode=:np.cast['int32'](1)})
```

and

```
test = theano.function([X], output, updates=update_G,
                       givens={train_mode=:np.cast['int32'](0)})
```

to my understanding, `givens` would input the value of `train_mode` (i.e. `1`/`0`) wherever it's needed to compute the output.

The `output` is computed in the lines of this:

```
     ...
     network2 = Net2()
     # This is sort of a dummy variable so I don't get a NameError when this
     # is called before `theano.function()` is called. Not sure if this is the
     # right way to do this.
     train_mode = T.iscalar('train_mode')
     output = loss(network1.get_outputs(network2.get_outputs(X, train_mode=train_mode)),something).mean()

 ....
 class Net2(): 
      def get_outputs(self, x, train_mode):
           from theano.ifelse import ifelse
           import theano.tensor as T
           my_flag = ifelse(T.eq(train_mode, 1), 1, 0)
           return something if my_flag else something_else
```

So `train_mode` is used as an argument in one of the nested functions, and I use it to tell between `train` and `test` as I'd like to handle them slightly differently.

However, when I try to run this, I get this error:

```
theano.compile.function_module.UnusedInputError: theano.function was
asked to create a function computing outputs given certain inputs, but
the provided input variable at index 1 is not part of the computational
graph needed to compute the outputs: <TensorType(int32, scalar)>.To make 
this error into a warning, you can pass the parameter 
on_unused_input='warn' to theano.function. To disable it completely, use 
on_unused_input='ignore'.
```

If I delete the `givens` parameter, the error disappears, so to my understanding Theano believes that my `train_mode` is not necessary for compute the `function()`. I can use `on_unusued_input='ignore'` as per their suggestion, but that would just ignore my `train_mode` if they think it's unused. Am I going around this the wrong way? I basically just want to train a neural network with dropout, but not use dropout when evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

why you use "=" sign? I think, it made train_mode not readable, my code works well by writing:
`givens = {train_mode:1}`

Comment: Sorry, the `=:` was a typo. I do the casting to keep the types consistent, but I'll give it a try without it when I get back to a computer.